# What are some good sites for researching etymology?

Tags: etymology, resources, online-resources

I'm wondering about the origins of a particular word and, while my first thought was to ask the ELU community, I decided I should do the work myself.

Where should I start looking? I'd love to see some suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to meta.

Comment: @Mitch We cannot migrate questions this old to meta.

Comment: The information can be copied and pasted into the resource post or something else on meta. I'm not sure why you reopened this @tchrist.

Comment: @Laurel I suppose they could be, but I would not be comfortable making believe that other people's answers were my own.

Comment: @tchrist Use disclaimers. This is obviously a request for resources, and belongs on ELU.Meta. Searchability is a prime requirement, and that means good collation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/) is a great resource for looking up specific words.
- If you are at a university, you might have [OED](http://oed.com) access, which is the most in-depth and hardcore etymology resource (if you can get to it).
- [Take Our Word For It](http://takeourword.com/) is a fun website for browsing through and learning about etymologies in a more entertaining, less structured way.

Comment: All great suggestions.  In my experience a lot of phrase or word etymologies will appear in one source but won't appear in another or vice versa, so my favorite method is still to just google each one and include the word etymology.

Comment: +! for OED, my absolute favorite–still pricy, good note on uni access

Comment: +1 again for the OED.  Many public libraries also have OED access, depending on where you live.

Comment: The University of Michigan version of OED V.2 will give you every example sentence that a given lemma occurs in (often more than 10,000 for common words), all dated, with source, in HTML for easy sorting. Wow. But only accessible if you have a umich.edu account, alas.

Answer (score 3):

General purpose:

- [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/)
- [Google Books](http://books.google.com/), set date range and sort by date*
- [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams)
- Bill Mullins has a giant list of [Full Text Databases](https://sites.google.com/site/fulltextdatabases/)
- [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/details/texts)
- [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/)
- [HathiTrust Digital Library](http://www.hathitrust.org/)
- [The Right Rhymes](http://www.therightrhymes.com/): hop-hop slang defined
- [Rap Stats by Rap Genius](http://rapgenius.com/rapstats) gives an idea of earliest use, but cannot be searched by time

Newspapers:

- USA: [Chronicling America](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/) (1836-1922) by the Library of Congress
- Australia: [Trove](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper) (-1954) by the National Library of Australia
- New Zealand: [Papers Past](http://paperspast.natlib.govt.nz/) (1839-1945) by the Nation Library of New Zealand

Particularly for computing terms:

- [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/) for Usenet archives (also good for slang) (1981 - present)
- [DSpace@MIT](http://dspace.mit.edu/) for the CSAIL archives (1959 - present)
- IETF's [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html) archive (1969 - present)
- [PDP-10 software](http://pdp-10.trailing-edge.com/cgi-bin/searchbyname) archive (~1967 - ~1990), for old source code
- [Tech Model Railroad Club dictionary](http://tmrc.mit.edu/dictionary.html), TMRC [1st & 2nd editions](http://www.gricer.com/tmrc/tmrc-dictionary-intro.html) (1959, 1960)
- [The Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/) and its [archives](http://jargon-file.org/archive/) ([also here](http://www.catb.org/jargon/oldversions/)) (1981 - 2003)
- MIT's [The Tech](https://thetech.com/issues) newspaper archives (1881 - present)
- [Bitsavers](http://www.bitsavers.org/)' Software and PDF Document Archive (misc. dates)

  * Care must be taken with Google Books' metadata, especially when only a snippet is shown: occasionally the book was published later than the the year Google claims it was, and sometimes they accidentally include multiple books for each record.

Therefore it's important to double check the date: scroll up to confirm the real date for "full view" books, and for preview/"snippet view" verify with another source (such as the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/details/texts), [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/) or the [HathiTrust Digital Library](http://www.hathitrust.org/)).

Comment: Someday someone (not me) will go through the first 50 years of computing and catalog the metaphors. **All** computing terms are metaphors, after all; , for instance files used to be cardboard (so things are IN them, while screens used to be paper (so things are ON them).

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add our etymology dictionary that draws directed etymology graphs called [Etymologeek.com](https://etymologeek.com).

Here is an example of a directed graph:
[image: directed etymology graph for the word elephant]

It works in multiple languages, providing etymology data, descendants, related words and more. It also has a pretty quick search, and the index is constantly growing in the number of words and slowly growing in accuracy too.