# Are there any good books or articles on the etymology of dermatology-related terminology and/or cutaneous condition names?

Tags: etymology

Are there any good books or articles on the etymology of dermatology-related terminology and/or cutaneous condition names?

[This list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cutaneous_conditions) is an example of some of the conditions/terminology I am referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dermatitis?match=fr#Etymology) and [FreeDict](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dermatitis) extensively. I find that breaking down scientific terms into their Greek and Latin roots helps me understand and remember the concepts that they represent. They lack any historical insight into the origins of the terms, however I found that this information could sometimes be found buried within a course textbook or a professor's brain. Also try searching for individual terms via Google, sometimes you get a hit.

Sorry I couldn't give you a solid hardcover. I hope someone else knows because I've been looking for a good scientific dictionary for a long time.

Comment: also see this post: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/what-are-some-good-sites-for-researching-etymology